# naming dataframe column vectors using `$`

Tags: r, dataframe

Can someone explain why in the below example the column name for `why` appears to remain `x` even though it is clearly named `why` and can be called as such but not for the column `zz`?

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5)
df$z<-"a"
df$zz<-df$x*df$y
df$why<-df[1]*df[2]

df

df["why"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're actually storing a dataframe into why - not a vector.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x  : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ y  : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ z  : chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ why:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ x: int  1 4 9 16 25
> str(df[1]*df[2])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  1 4 9 16 25
> str(df[,1] * df[,2])
 int [1:5] 1 4 9 16 25  
> df$why2 <- df[,1]*df[,2]
> df
  x y z  x why2
1 1 1 a  1    1
2 2 2 a  4    4
3 3 3 a  9    9
4 4 4 a 16   16
5 5 5 a 25   25
```

`df[1]` returns the first element of df as a sublist.  A dataframe is a special type of list which is why you can use this type of indexing to grab columns.  However only using the single bracket tells it to return a sublist containing the element of interest (instead of just the element of interest).

Comment: i won't forget my `[,]` anymore

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem is indexing, try this:

```
df$zz<-df$x*df$y       # this should replace df$zz<-x*y
df$why<-df[,1]*df[,2]  # this repaces df$why<-df[1]*df[2]

df
  x y z zz why
1 1 1 a  1   1
2 2 2 a  4   4
3 3 3 a  9   9
4 4 4 a 16  16
5 5 5 a 25  25

df["why"]
  why
1   1
2   4
3   9
4  16
5  25
```